How to replace substrate address(H256) to Ethereum Address(H160)
I need to replace the substrate address(H256) in fresh substrate-node-template to Ethereum Address(H160). Is it possible?
If yes, Is it mandatory to integrate frontier in the node-template?
Do we have any resources to tackle this problem?
